# Javascript or PHP watermark or overlay an image to an image

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm programming a game in which users predict which quadrant a particular meteor will hit. After each round, I would like to add an image of a "crater" to the map, depending on which quadrant the meteor hits (using PHP rand(1,4)).

The map itself is an image... Just wondering if there was anything on PHP or Javascript to edit the image and progressively watermark or overlay it after each round? Or, should this be accomplished through HTML canvas?

Comment: canvas, or use semi-transparent .gifs

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to use canvas if you don't want to. You could use JavaScript and CSS to position your images where you want them. I'll expand on this if it sounds useful.